# Apache Redirects in FilesMatch directive

Tags: apache, redirect

In my httpd-vhosts.conf file, I have 30 rewrite rules. I want that requests of .css type should not go through that 30 rewrite rules.

I have used

```
<filesMatch "!\.(css)$">
        ReWriteRule ^/welcome1.html$ /retail-en_us/home.page [P,L,QSA]
  ReWriteRule ^/welcome3.html$ /retail-en_us/home.page [P,L,QSA]
ReWriteRule ^/welcome4.html$ /retail-en_us/home.page [P,L,QSA]
ReWriteRule ^/whychoose.html$ /retail-en_us/whytdameritrade.page [P,L,QSA]
ReWriteRule ^/portfolioac/overview.html$ /retail-en_us/account-types/standard.page [P,L,QSA]
ReWriteRule ^/trade/overview.html$ /retail-en_us/investment-products.page [P,L,QSA]
ReWriteRule ^/planningforretirement.html$ /retail-en_us/retirement-planning/retirement-suite.page [P,L,QSA]
ReWriteRule ^/tradingtools/overview.html$ /retail-en_us/tools-and-platforms.page [P,L,QSA]
ReWriteRule ^/tradingtools/browsealltools.html$ /retail-en_us/tools-and-platforms/tools-and-calculators.page [P,L,QSA]
ReWriteRule ^/tradingtools/advanced.html$ /retail-en_us/tools-and-platforms/thinkorswim/features.page [P,L,QSA]
ReWriteRule ^/tradingtools/charting.html$ /retail-en_us/tools-and-platforms/trade-architect/features.page [P,L,QSA]
```

......
....
..

This is not working as if I am accessing any rewrite rule within this  .. , it is not accessible. Please help if there is any other way of restricting .css from accessing those rewrite-rules